# Why does String have no attribute to message of the author?

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord bot that stores the message I sent, but I always keep on getting this error

**`File "main.py", line 55, in on_message     response = client.wait_for(author=content.author, timeout=30)`** **`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message'`**

I tried to look into lots of sites and youtube videos on how to solve it but it won't work. can someone help please?

**Here is my code**

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = message.content
    
  
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if ctx.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    if ctx.startswith('$info'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi I am slantbot. so far I am just a test but anyways more info will be put soon! See you then.')  

    if ctx.startswith('$2idtest'):
      response = client.wait_for(author=ctx.message.author, timeout=30) 
      myvar = response.content
      await message.channel.send(myvar)
      
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: You first did `ctx = message.content`, so ctx is a string. Then you're trying to do `ctx.message.author`, which is where you get the error. Did you mean to just do `message.author`?

Comment: I Changed it to `message.author`  but now I get this error `TypeError: wait_for() got an unexpected keyword argument 'author'`